# How do I add more pages to views pagination on mobile?

Tags: views, 8

I'm using Open Social and I want to add more pages to the paginationon mobile phones.

One of my views has 11 pages of users and on mobile the pagination is as the following example (<< = previous page, >> = next page):

```
<< 5 >>
```

Now what I want to achieve is the following:

```
<< 3 4 5 6 7 >>
```

Now I have searched through all the settings but I can't seem to find where to change this. I believe it should be in the code but no luck so far either. Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You must do this in the views configuration.

First you need to set the pager to use `full pager` instead of `mini pager`.

[image]

Then in the settings you can set the amount of pager links visible (in your case 5).

[image]

That should show the pager you want with 5 pager links visible.

Comment: I knew this was a thing, I've tried it but shamefully it doesn't change a thing. Its standard value is 9 but changing it to 5 doesn't change the pagination. Also: On desktop it shows correct, but on mobile I just see 1 page which I'd like to see different

Comment: It should work maybe you have some custom code that overrides it?